# How to multiply fixed-point numbers if fixed and fractional part are stored separately?

Tags: c, math, addition

I want to multiply two fixed-point numbers with different fractional length.
Fixed point part and fractional one are stored separately:

```
123    . 4
fix    . frac
sint32 . sint32
```

I use two variables, one for the fixed part and one for the fractional one.

I tried to use the Karatsuba algorithm. But this one is working only with fixed length of fractional. The fractional part of the two numbers is varying. They could be the same, but there is any guarantee for this.
Of course, the max possible value is (2^32) - 1.

What is the best way to multiply 123.4 with 56.789?

```
// a = 123.4
signed int a_fxd = 123;
signed int a_frx = 4;
// b = 56.789
signed int b_fxd = 56
signed int b_frc = 789;
```

Comment: Side remark: in your first code block you say uint32 but in the second one you use signed!?

Comment: @Hagadol I have corrected.

Comment: How do you represent 123.04?

Comment: @kakkoko 1 min ago
signed int a_fxd = 123;
signed int a_frx = 4;

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008330/how-do-you-multiply-two-fixed-point-numbers

Comment: But a_fxd = 123; a_frx = 4 can can also represent 123.4, 123.004, 123.0004, ...

Comment: @dash-o  
Input data length is 16 bit. I shall multiply two 16 bit numbers. In worst case i need 32 bit for the result. Since I shall also multiply with some sin(x)value, I have also fractional part. So, i shall separate the fixed part and fractional part into two 32 bit variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide what the actual *scaling factor* for your fractional part is.  For your particular example, it looks like an appropriate factor might be 1/1000, or 0.001.  What this means is that 56.789 is represented as 56 + 789 × 0.001.  But it means that 123.4 will be represented as 12 + 400 × 0.001.  That is, you had a mistake in your question: `a_frx` will be 400, not 4.

I don't know [Karatsuba's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), and I suspect it's not really applicable to this problem anyway.  I only know what I earned in elementary school.

Let's represent the scaling factor by `sc`.  So our multiplication is actually

```
( a_fxd + a_frx * sc ) * ( b_fxd + b_frx * sc )
```

Multiplying this out, we get

```
a_fxd * b_fxd + a_fxd * b_frx * sc + a_frx * b_fxd * sc + a_frx * b_frx * sc * sc
```

Collecting terms, we have

```
a_fxd * b_fxd + (a_fxd * b_frx + a_frx * b_fxd + a_frx * b_frx * sc) * sc
```

So if we represent the product as `p_fxd` and `p_frx`, it looks like we'll have

```
p_fxd = a_fxd * b_fxd
p_frx = a_fxd * b_frx + a_frx * b_fxd + a_frx * b_frx * sc
```

Let's plug in the actual values:

```
p_fxd = 123 * 56 = 6888
p_frx = 123 * 789 + 400 * 56 + 400 * 789 * 0.001 = 119762.600
```

But there's an additional wrinkle, because `p_frx` is really supposed to be an integer in the range 0..999.  So we need to discard the .600, and carry the 119.  So our final result is

```
p_fxd = 6888 + 119 = 7007
p_frx = 762
```

And this corresponds to the correct result, 123.4 × 56.789 = 7007.762.

...Well, actually, the *correct* correct result is 7007.7626, or rounded to three digits, 7007.763.  So strictly speaking we shouldn't have thrown away that .600 we ended up with in `p_frx`, we should have rounded.

There may also be some extra wrinkles to take care of when we consider the possibility of negative numbers.

Finally, there's the choice of scaling factor.  In practice, the 0.001 I've used here isn't really a realistic value.  For a general-purpose algorithm you'd probably use something more like 1/10000, or 1/1000000000, or 1/32768, or 1/65536, or something like that.  (Using powers of two makes for larger ranges and typically more efficient calculations, but less-obvious fractional parts and less-efficient conversions to and from decimal representations.  For example, if you used a scaling factor of 1/32768, `a_frx` would be 13107, and `b_frx` would be 25853 or 25854.)